# How to setuid by using Itamae

Tags: ruby, itamae

I want to change file attributes using [Itamae](https://github.com/itamae-kitchen/itamae), so I wrote this:

```
file '/usr/local/bin/jobber' do
  action :edit
  owner 'jobber_client'
  group 'root'
  mode '04755'
end
```

The `owner` and `group` attributes were changed as expected, but `mode` only changed to `755` without performing the `setuid` to the file.

How can I perform a `setuid` with `Itamae`?

Comment: Can you try to use the `user` param on **file** resource : https://github.com/itamae-kitchen/itamae/wiki/file-resource

Comment: what value should I set for `user` param?

Comment: Here's the patch I commited :
https://github.com/itamae-kitchen/itamae/commit/bdcba8e19bcd1f36a2f5af6ab51733c5682013d3

Answer (score 2):

There was a [bug filed against Chef](https://github.com/chef/chef/issues/2951) for a similar issue, which seems to have been fixed [here](https://github.com/chef/chef/pull/2967).

If Itamae is also affected by the same issue, then creating the file first and then modifying it later seems to be the best workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Itamae doesn't ignore '4xxx', but it calls chmod first and then chown. Problem is : chown removes the suid set by chmod.

You can see it with

```
itamae local recipe.rb --log-level=debug
```

Swapping positions of the two ifs :

```
        if attributes.mode
          run_specinfra(:change_file_mode, change_target, attributes.mode)
        end

        if attributes.owner || attributes.group
          run_specinfra(:change_file_owner, change_target, attributes.owner, attributes.group)
        end
```

in def action_create(options) and def action_edit(options) at https://github.com/itamae-kitchen/itamae/blob/master/lib/itamae/resource/file.rb does the trick

I'll submit a patch.

In the meantime, this seems to work :

```
jobber = '/usr/local/bin/jobber'

file jobber do
  action :edit
  owner 'jobber_client'
  group 'root'
  mode '0755'
end

execute "setuid #{jobber}" do
  command "chmod u+s \"#{jobber}\""
end
```